# How to Formulate a Constraint Which Ensures All Variables Have the Same Sign

Tags: matlab, optimization, convex-optimization, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to include a constraint in my problem (to be solved by any convex optimization solver). Let {a,b,c,d ...} be a finite set of continuous variables. How to formulate a constraint which ensure all of these variables, in the same time interval, take either "positive or zero" or "negative or zero" values.

sincerely,

Mohan

Comment: A simple $\mathrm(sign)$ function would be suffice right?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Maxtron but that doesn't answer my question. Here's what I was looking for https://orinanobworld.blogspot.com/2018/09/coordinating-variable-signs.html

Comment: The way it is done in the blog you posted means the problem becomes Non Convex. So I'm not sure it would work for you.

Comment: @MohanLal, Could you please mark my answer or write what is missing?

Answer (score 5):

The solution from the blog you linked goes as following ([Coordinating Variable Signs by Paul Rubin](https://orinanobworld.blogspot.com/2018/09/coordinating-variable-signs.html), [Web Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20200128175341/https://orinanobworld.blogspot.com/2018/09/coordinating-variable-signs.html)):

> Someone asked me today (or yesterday, depending on whose time zone you
> go by) how to force a group of variables in an optimization model to
> take the same sign (all nonpositive or all nonnegative). Assuming that
> all the variables are bounded, you just need one new binary variable
> and a few constraints.
>
> Assume that the variables in question are $ {x}_{1}, {x}_{2}, \ldots, {x}_{n} $ and that they are all bounded, say $ \forall \; 1 \leq i \leq n, \; {l}_{i} \leq {x}_{i} \leq {u}_{i} $.   If we are going to
> allow variables to be either positive or negative, then clearly we
> need $ {l}_{i} < 0 < {u}_{i} $.   We introduce a new binary variable $ y \in \left\{ 0, 1 \right\} $ and for each $ i $ the constraints
> become:
>
> $$ \forall \; 1 \leq i \leq n, \; {l}_{i} \left( 1 - y \right) \leq {x}_{i} \leq {u}_{i} y $$
>
> If $ y = 0 $ every original variable must be between its lower bound
> and 0, nonpositive. If $ y = 1 $ every original variable must be
> between 0 and its upper bound, nonnegative.
>
> Note that trying to enforce strictly positive or strictly negative
> rather than nonnegative or nonpositive is problematic, since
> optimization models abhor strict inequalities. The only work around I
> know is to change "strictly positive" to "greater than or equal to $
> > \epsilon $" for some strictly positive $ \epsilon $, which creates
> holes in the domains of the variables (making values between 0 and $ \epsilon $ infeasible).

The problem with above approach is that it will make a Convex Optimization Problem into Non Convex Optimization Problem because of the multiplication between variables.

For many solvers I guess it will make no difference. Yet if you use Convex Optimization solver or even Disciplined Convex Programming (DCP) based solver (Like CVX) it won't work.

What I suggest doing, in this case, is take advantage that you have only 2 cases. One where all variables are Non Negative and the other when all of them are Non Positive.

Then all you need is to solve the problem with 2 different sets of constraints (Forming 2 different problems). When the constraints are:

- $ \forall \; 1 \leq i \leq n, \; {l}_{i} \leq {x}_{i} \leq 0 $
- $ \forall \; 1 \leq i \leq n, \; 0 \leq {x}_{i} \leq {u}_{i} $

Then chose the solution with the lowest objective value.

The main advantage is while the solution using Binary Variable (Which probably will do the same) require special MILP / MIQP solver the approach I suggested, for Linear Least Squares problem only require Non Negative Least Squares solver which is easier to find (Usually faster).

### Example with Code

Let's say we want to solve the following problem:

$$\begin{aligned}
\arg \min_{x} \quad & \frac{1}{2} {\left\| A x - b \right\|}_{2}^{2} \\
\text{subject to} \quad & \operatorname{sign} \left( {x}_{i} \right) = \operatorname{sign} \left( {x}_{j} \right) && \forall i, j \in \mathcal{S}
\end{aligned}$$

Where $ \mathcal{S} = \left\{ i \mid {x}_{i} \neq 0 \right\} $, namely the set of all indices for which the element of $ x $ isn't zero.
So basically we say all elements should have the same sign or be zero.

Let's say we have a building block for solving [Non Negative Least Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_least_squares). For instance one could use [MATLAB's `lsqnonneg()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lsqnonneg.html).
To solve the problem above one could solve it one time for $ A $ and the other for $ - A $. Then take the argument which minimize the objective (If we take the argument of $ - A $ we need to negate it).

So the MATLAB function would look like:

```
function [ vX ] = SolveLsSameSign( mA, vB )

[vX1, resNorm1] = lsqnonneg(mA, vB);
[vX2, resNorm2] = lsqnonneg(-mA, vB);

if(resNorm1 < resNorm2)
    vX = vX1;
else
    vX = -vX2;
end

end
```

I created a simple script to compare results to CVX using the [Mixed Integer Quadratic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming#Integer_constraints) (MIQP) which is given by:

```
cvx_solver('Mosek');
% cvx_solver('Gurobi');

cvx_begin()
    % cvx_precision('best');
    variable vX(numCols, 1);
    variable varY(1) binary;
    minimize( norm(mA * vX - vB, 2) );
    subject to
        vX >= (1 - varY) * lowerBound;
        vX <= varY * upperBound;
cvx_end
```

Pay attention that it requires *MOSEK* or *Gurobi* to be installed in order to solve this MIQP problem.

The full MATLAB code is available on my [StackExchange Signal Processing Q52099 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes) (Look at the `SignalProcessing\Q52099` folder).

Comment: Great idea! I think you should show a sample code.

Comment: @David, I added a simple example.